# Can I create a Liftable for a parameterized trait in Scala 3 macros?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros, scala-3

```scala
sealed trait Foo[T]
case class A() extends Foo[String]
case class B[V](v: V) extends Foo[Int]

given ToExpr[A] with {
  def apply(x: A)(using Quotes) =
    '{ A() }
}

given ToExpr[B] with {
  def apply(x: B[_])(using Quotes) =
    '{ B(x.v) }
}

inline def of[T]: RType[T] = ${ ofImpl[T]() }

def ofImpl[T]()(using quotes:Quotes)): Expr[Foo[T]] =
  import quotes.reflect.*
  Expr( B(15).asInstanceOf[RType[T]] ) // <<<---Doesn't work ;-)
```

I need my macro to return the generalized Foo[T], not the specific implementation.

Any way to do this?

Comment: What is `RType`? `Expr.apply` can only be used if `ToExpr` exist which is defined virtualy only for: primitives, tuples, options and eithers - basically build-in constants. Have you tried quoting? `'{ B(15).asInstanceOf[RType[T]] }`? And do you want to eventually build AST dynamically or just inline some (generic but unchanged) piece of code because you don't need compile-time reflection for that.